# ASP.NET MVC Custom Authorize Attribute with Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a web application using ASP.NET MVC that has two very distinct types of users. Admin, full access on the system and Users, but the users required the validation of date. This a "license" for users by date (start and end).

I am using the built-in ASP.NET authorization, i was thinking about storing the users in the UsersProfile (WebMatrix) and add the table for companies, for create a license. I call the procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_CompaniesIsActive]

@IsActive BIT OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME SET @DateNow = GETDATE()
IF EXISTS (
SELECT Result=CAST(
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT C.[Id], C.[Start], C.[End], U.[CompaniesId], U.[UserId]
    FROM Companies AS C INNER JOIN UserProfile AS U
    ON U.CompaniesId = C.Id
    WHERE
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [End], 102)) > CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DateNow, 102))
)
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
)

SET @IsActive=1
Else
SET @IsActive=0
End
```

I need help for create a "public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute" and call in the controller.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question, exactly? What have you tried, and what is the problem that you're running into?

Comment: I'm completely lost. I tried to make a custom class AuthorizeAttribute but have not found any examples that describe how to recognize the BIT and the procedure say whether or not the person can access the system.
For exemplo, if 0 not access, if 1 access.

Comment: Why don't you just check the security from within the controller method?  AuthorizeAttribute does not have access to the database unless you hand it a connection, and you can't pass AuthorizeAttribute any parameters like the user id.  You're better off just checking security like that in the controller method.

Comment: Hi Robert. Thanks for help. and can you give me a idea on how can I do? it must inform the user that it can not connect because the date of his contract ended. thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way to do this is to use the standard `AuthorizeAttribute` in conjunction with a custom `RoleProvider`.  Google will show you how to implement a custom `RoleProvider` - basically as a minimum you need to implement the `GetRolesForUser` and `IsUserInRole` methods.

Your custom RoleProvider can return a list of roles that include your standard roles (Admin, User) as well as a role (e.g. "LicensedUser") that will only be returned if the user is currently licensed.

> i still do not understand how I will implement a check for a specific role.

The basics of your "GetRolesForUser" method might look something like:

```
public string[] GetRolesForUser(string userName)
{
    // Get "standard" roles (User, Admin) ...
    List<string> roles = GetStandardRolesForUser(string userName);

    if (IsUsersCompanyActive(userName))
    {
        roles.Add("LicensedUser");
    }
    return roles.ToArray();
}
```

Here `GetStandardRolesForUser` gets the User, Admin roles from wherever you're storing it.  And `IsUsersCompanyActive` checks if the user's company is currently active.

Comment: Hi Joe, can you give me an example, a link or something? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Joe. I researched better about your answer, and i still do not understand how I will implement a check for a specific role. because if just create the role, I have a functional RoleProvider. Thanks.

Comment: @fsharp - It's simple.  You have User and LicensedUser roles.  Your role provider checks the dates for the user in the database, and returns LicensedUser when the user is within the date range, otherwise it returns User.  You then simply use the normal Authorize attribute to prevent access to the areas you only want LicensedUsers to access.

Comment: Hi Joe. understood. I will try later and post here if I could. thank you very much.

Comment: @Joe I do not know implement, I'm newbie and I'm still learning about asp.net. But I need to implement this in a system and do not know how, can you help me more? With further example, etc. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @Joe. how do I use the Custom Authorization Attribute with this stored procedure. may be simpler. implement a:
     [LicenseAuthorizeAttribute]
     public ActionResult Index()

and create a class:

    namespace MySystem.Filters
    {
    [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class |     AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class LicenseAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
    }
but how to implement?
THANKS!!!

Comment: I don't agree it's simpler to create a custom AuthorizationAttribute.  Also it increases coupling, since your Controller will be explicitly dependent on your custom attribute.